# Colab: Cannot run any cell after changing the runtime to local

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm new to Tensorflow and I just started using Google Colab a week ago, and I want to run it locally so that it can use my own CPU to avoid [Colab Resource Restrictions](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#resource-limits), so I followed the [Official guide on running Colab locally](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html), and after I'm all set and try to run any cell in the Colab, it pops up this error:

[image]

And then immediately changed to this -

[image: Error after running a cell]

And here is the full runtime logs it gave me:

```
    Could not fetch resource at : 404 Not Found 
FetchError: Could not fetch resource at : 404 Not Found 
    at ny.fr [as constructor] (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20210513-060327-RC00_373550014:684:397)
    at new ny (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20210513-060327-RC00_373550014:1299:1093)
    at za.program_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20210513-060327-RC00_373550014:5067:158)
    at Ba (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20210513-060327-RC00_373550014:19:336)
    at za.next_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20210513-060327-RC00_373550014:17:503)
    at Ca.next (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20210513-060327-RC00_373550014:20:206)
    at f (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20210513-060327-RC00_373550014:61:101)
```

Since I've been struggling with this error all day, and I also reinstall and upgrade the Python, TensorFlow as well as the jupyter-notebook a few times, so PLEASE HELP ME!!! Or if anyone knows how to change the runtime back to browser will also be helpful, I'm kind of stuck here...

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you are new to colab, just double checking the basics - did you try [Connect Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQYVT.png) (in top right area of colab) and choosing "Connect to Local Run time"?

Also note that sometimes large datasets cause out of memory error, so that might be one cause too.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply :). But that's definitely what I did, and I also don't think just importing tensorflow as tf will going to cause memory issues~